# how to Split String By \ in java

Tags: java

I am having problem to split string in java. it gives  `java.util.regex.Pattern.error`.

```
 String name = One\Two\Three.
 String[] str = name.split("\\");
 for(int i =0; i < str.length ; i++)
    System.out.println(str[i]);
```

I put another \ as escape character but not working.

help me.

Comment: Have you tried just splitting using the char value of 92 or the UTF-8?

In Unicode, it is encoded at U+005C \ reverse solidus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`One\Two\Three` is not a valid string literal (you need quotes and you need to escape the backslashes).

```
String name = "One\\Two\\Three.";
String[] str = name.split("\\\\");
for(int i =0; i < str.length ; i++)
   System.out.println(str[i]);
```

[works fine](http://ideone.com/Po6Ba).

#### Explanation

`String#split` expects a regular expression. The backslash character has a special meaning inside regular expressions, so you need to escape it by using another backslash: `\\` Now because the backslash character also has a special meaning inside Java string literals, you have to double each of these *again*, resulting in `"\\\\"`.

Comment: Why is it that your Regex has 4 Backslash instead of 2?

Comment: \\ is an escape sequence used to represent \ for example, to have a " in a string you need to put \"

Comment: String Comes out side of my application. when i show string in debug mode it displays as "One\\Two\\Three." is any other way?

Comment: @Dipesh: `"One\\Two\\Three."` is the correct representation of that string. No, there's no other way, you just have to accept the fact that backslashes have a special meaning inside string literals. They're used as an escape character, so they need to be escaped properly if they are not used that way.

Comment: Thanks Niklas B I know,and i accept that i have to put backslash for removing special meaning and it works while i use 4 backslash as name.split("\\\\"); and it works

Comment: @Dipesh: It doesn't surprise me that it works, the linked IDEone link speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the quotes

```
String name = "One\\Two\\Three".
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it twice:

```
 String name = "One\\Two\\Three."
 String[] str = name.split("\\\\");
 for(int i =0; i < str.length ; i++)
    System.out.println(str[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your pattern you should use this tool:

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/RegexTester/regex-tester.html

You cant write your test String there and your test Pattern and it can call the methods matches(), lookingAt(), find() and reset(). Also it translates your pattern to Java code (escaping the backslashes and such).